# The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value (EntLib 5 + ODP.NET)

Tags: database, enterprise-library, odp.net, data-access, enterprise-library-5

I use ODP.NET and version 4.1 of the Enterprise Library, vs 2008. And all is OK.

Now, migrate using ODP.NET Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.2.0 and version 5.0.414.0 of the Enterprise Library, vs 2010, .net 4.0.

Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.2.0
EnterpriseLibrary 5.0.414.0

Following a recent upgrade from version 4.1 to 5.0 of the Enterprise Library, once we get the following error:

"The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value."

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation
>   error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key
>   "ConnectionStrings.Oracle.xxx" --->
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name =
>   "ConnectionStrings.Oracle.xxx". Exception occurred while: while
>   resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Database
>   cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this
>   value.

References EntLib Forum: http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/215290

any solution about it ??

my config

```
<configSections>

<section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=709072f976b4c05b"/>

<section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=709072f976b4c05b" />
</configSections>

<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="ConnectionStrings.Oracle.xxx"/>

<connectionStrings>

<add name="ConnectionStrings.Oracle.xxx" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=des;PASSWORD=zzz;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=aaa;"
providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

My Code

```
 var key = "ConnectionStrings.Oracle.xxx";

            Database db = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>(key); //~(EntLib 5 recommended)


            using (DbCommand cm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("TBL_FRKDATA.TBL_FRKDATA_FND_ALL"))
            {
                cm.Parameters.Add(CreateCursorParameter("P_REFCURSOR"));

                // Using "using" will cause both the DataReader and connection to be 
                // closed. (ExecuteReader will close the connection when the 
                // DataReader is closed.)
                using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(cm))
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        builder.Add(dataReader);
                    }
                    return builder.EntityList;

                }
            }
```

full error stacktrace

> Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext
>   context, SelectedConstructor selectedConstructor)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext
>   context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t,
>   Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name,
>   ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String
>   key)

UPDATE

this code works for me:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Conectar_con_EntLib_y_OdpNet_Test()
    {
        var key = "ConnectionStrings.Oracle.xxx";

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
        string providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ProviderName;

        //Database db = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>(key);

        TestContext.WriteLine("connectionString: " + connectionString);
        TestContext.WriteLine("providerName: " + providerName);

        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

        using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            connection.Open();

            TestContext.WriteLine("Estado Conexión: " + connection.State);
            connection.Close();
        }



    }
```

Solution: by Randy Levy (http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/215290)

You can't use the Enterprise Library OracleDatabase with the Oracle.DataAccess.Client provider.  The built in OracleDatabase is hardcoded to 
use the OracleClientFactory DbProviderFactory whereas you want to use the ODP.NET provider (Oracle.DataAccess.Client).

The best way is to get the EntLibContrib Oracle ODP.NET Data Provider working since it should support everything that you need including configuration files.

Since it looks like you can create the DbProviderFactory you could try to use a GenericDatabase with the ODP.NET OracleClientFactory but I would guess that 
you would run into issues for specific Oracle functionality (e.g. refcursor).

You could use it directly:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection String"].ConnectionString;
string providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection String"].ProviderName;

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
var db = new GenericDatabase(connectionString, factory);
```

Comment: Quick check [MSDN Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953187(v=PandP.50).aspx). States `However, keep in mind that the OracleClient provider is deprecated in version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, although it is still supported by Enterprise Library. For future development, consider choosing a different Oracle driver.`

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030436/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-database-key or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900403/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-logwriter

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient.dll is deprecated in .NET 4.0. But ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) is supported in .NET 4.0. The question is using Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.112.2.0 and EntLib 5.0.

Comment: I have used EntLib Config Wiz, and when I add Oracle Connection String it adds `<section name="oracleConnectionSettings" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.Configuration.OracleConnectionSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />` and `<oracleConnectionSettings>`. Can you try EntLib Config Wiz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
```

then use this line to get the database:

```
var database = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
```

More info here: http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/enterprise-library-5-with-odp-net/

Comment: I'm still getting the error after this. I also forced 32-bit and then 64-bit in the build and in IIS per the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolve changing the Application Pool "Enable 32 bit Applications" to true.

Comment: Had this come up on a windows service (so not specifically 'Enable 32 bit applications'). But it was 'code compiled to 32 bit, server only had 64 bit Oracle client'. We recompiled the code to 64 bit and were able to deploy to server and it worked.